# In C, How to split a string on \n into lines

Tags: c, split, strtok

I want to split a string by `\n` and place lines which contain a specific token into an array.

I have this code:

```
char mydata[100] = 
    "mary likes apples\njim likes playing\nmark hates school\nanne likes mary";
char *token = "likes";
char ** res  = NULL;
char * p = strtok (mydata, "\n");
int n_spaces = 0, i;
/* split string and append tokens to 'res' */
while (p) {
    res = realloc (res, sizeof (char*) * ++n_spaces);
    if (res == NULL)
    exit (-1); /* memory allocation failed */
    if (strstr(p, token))
        res[n_spaces-1] = p;
    p = strtok (NULL, "\n");
}
/* realloc one extra element for the last NULL */
res = realloc (res, sizeof (char*) * (n_spaces+1));
res[n_spaces] = '\0';
/* print the result */
for (i = 0; i < (n_spaces+1); ++i)
    printf ("res[%d] = %s\n", i, res[i]);
/* free the memory allocated */
free (res);
```

But then I get a segmentation fault:

```
res[0] = mary likes apples
res[1] = jim likes playing
Segmentation fault
```

How can I split a string on `\n` correctly in C?

Comment: Can you use a regular expression?

Comment: I don't wanna use regex

Comment: Without even reading your code, I am pretty sure that, if you have segmentation fault issues, it means that you have not checked for the end-of-string (or null) character: '\0'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strstr` just returns a pointer to the first match of second argument.

Your code is not taking care of null character.

Can use `strcpy` to copy string.

```
while (p) {
  // Also you want string only if it contains "likes"

    if (strstr(p, token))
    {
        res = realloc (res, sizeof (char*) * ++n_spaces);
        if (res == NULL)
          exit (-1); 
        res[n_spaces-1] = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(p));

        strcpy(res[n_spaces-1],p);
     }
    p = strtok (NULL, "\n");
}
```

Free `res` using:

```
for(i = 0; i < n_spaces; i++)
    free(res[i]);
free(res);
```

Comment: I forgot to ask you something ... can you give me a hint about how to add to res[i] not the whole line but let's say without first 3 chars? something like:  "ry likes apples" instead of "mary likes apples" I tried to decrease the length but it gives me another segmentation fault. Thanks

Comment: @SamReina may be `strcpy(res[n_spaces-1],p+3);`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
char mydata[100] = "mary likes apples\njim likes playing\nmark hates school\nanne likes mary";
char *token = "likes";
char **result = NULL;
int count = 0;
int i;
char *pch;

// split
pch = strtok (mydata,"\n");
while (pch != NULL)
{
    if (strstr(pch, token) != NULL)
    {
        result = (char*)realloc(result, sizeof(char*)*(count+1));
        result[count] = (char*)malloc(strlen(pch)+1);
        strcpy(result[count], pch);
        count++;
    }
    pch = strtok (NULL, "\n");
}

// show and free result
printf("%d results:\n",count);
for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    printf ("result[%d] = %s\n", i, result[i]);
    free(result[i]);
}
free(result);
```